# Response notification under "StackExchange", but can't find the response. Deleted?

Tags: support

I had a notification of activity on my question under main, but I can't find it.  Does that mean it was deleted?  Here's what I show:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvfrm.jpg]

(Can't embed image due to new user restriction. I thought they were lifted AT 10 points, based on the listing with percentage points I got, but I guess it's at 11?)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's exactly what it means. That question has a deleted answer on it that matches the text you see in the inbox.